# Translate a single line into a file with one shell command

Tags: shell, sed, variable, parameter

I'm looking for a convenient command to run from my terminal. At now I'm using

```bsh
$> FILE=./file_for_translate.md && ROW=84 && \
DATA=$(sed -n ''"$ROW"'p' $FILE | trans -no-init -no-warn -b -t ru) && \
sed -i ''"$ROW"'a '"$DATA"'' $FILE
```

for translating the 84th row to Russian and insert the line after the current one.

But I need swap the variables declaration with execution. It's something like this

```bsh
$> YADA_YADA < FILE=./file_for_translate.md && ROW=84
```

for my experiments with `sed` and `trans`.

Important. I do not need a script in my environment or some external call. My goal is a one-line command with the ability to edit parameters on the right.

Comment: Create a bash function with 2 arguments, one being the filename and one being the row. Then replace your variables with `"$1"` and `"$2"` respectively.

Comment: @Panki You're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @panki said It was simple:

```bsh
$> fn(){DATA=$(sed -n ''"$2"'p' $1 | trans -no-init -no-warn -b -t ru) && \
sed -i ''"$2"'a '"$DATA"'' $1} && \
fn file_for_transalate.md 82
```